# Are “let” and “lets” used properly...?

Tags: verbs, synonyms, bare-infinitive

If *let* means to ‘give permission to’ or ‘allow’ then *lets* means ‘allows’ or ‘gives permission to’ then

is *inthebushbook* lets you to connect...correct?

why or why not?

Comment: "Let's" means "let us", thus "X let us you do something awesome", which makes no sense, and is ungrammatical.

Comment: It's 'allows you to connect' but 'lets you connect', if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to think that _lets_ is a plural, but it is a verb in the third person _singular_. So _lets_ means _give**s** permission_, not _give permission**s**_.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say "allow(s) you *connect*" or "let(s) you *to* connect".

Yes, it is correct to say "allow(s) you *to* connect" or "let(s) you *connect*".

Some verbs in English are used with "bare infinitives" and other verbs are used with "to infinitives". You just have to learn the correct construction with each verb: it isn't based on the verb's meaning, so sometimes synonyms, like "let" and "allow", have different grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mari-lou A for a good answer and helping clean my question up.

I was mainly looking for why... I found a sufficient answer myself so I am posting it...

I understand that connect is a bare infinitive in this case.  I understand that this is to help make the sentence flow better or in other words...

From Cambridge English Corpus...

When the bare infinitive is used, the activity described in the infinitival phrase is never interrupted, almost as if there is an entailment relation.

The perfective reading associated with the bare infinitive derives from the interpretation of the perception verb as stative.